# What is the most performant way to draw a large number of simple, colour-filled rectangles with a set FPS in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to fill a square-shaped CustomPaint Widget with a large number of random, colour-filled rectangles. The animation needs to be updated at a set FPS rate. I have a working demo, but even with only a 100x100 random matrix, the max FPS seems to be around 30 on my phone. The code needs to be cross-platform (android and iOS).

I am new to Flutter, and I was wondering if there was a more performant way of generating this animation. The logic is not complex at all, but I guess the high number of random value generation and the thousands of tiny rectangles are a challenge to generate in a timely manner. On native android, I used openGL and GLSurfaceView, and I was hoping that Flutter has something equally performant ...

here is a link to my code: https://gist.github.com/ize8/f734b9d62d78c74667a845f211e06fb7

```dart
import 'dart:math';
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'CustomPaint Animation'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  
  bool _isRunning = true; //is the animation running?
  var _fps = new List.filled(20, 0.0); //list for the last 20 FPS
  int _pos = 0; //position for logging FPS

  final _rnd = Random();
  final _rowSize = 100;//how many rectangles in a row
  final _freq = -1; //the maximum FPS, -1 if no limit

  List _matrix;

  Ticker _ticker;
  Duration lastTick = Duration(milliseconds: 0);

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _matrix = _generateMatrix();//generate random set
    _ticker = createTicker((Duration elapsed) {
      var diff = elapsed.inMicroseconds - lastTick.inMicroseconds;//time elapsed since last tick
      var currentFps = 1000000 / diff;//calculate current FPS
      if (currentFps <= _freq || _freq == -1) {
        setState(() {
          _fps[_pos] = currentFps;//save FPS into list
          lastTick = elapsed;
          _matrix = _generateMatrix(); //generate new random set
        });
        if (_pos < _fps.length - 1)
          _pos += 1;
        else
          _pos = 0;
      }
    });
    _ticker.start();//start ticker
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _ticker.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  //generate new random set of color codes 0-3
  List _generateMatrix() {
    return new List.generate(_rowSize * _rowSize, (int i) => _rnd.nextInt(4),
        growable: false);
  }

  void _toggleDynamic(bool isRunning) {
    setState(() {
      _isRunning = isRunning;
    });
    if (isRunning)
      _ticker.start();
    else
      _ticker.stop();
  }

  //calculate average FPS from list
  double _getAvgFps() {
    return _fps.reduce((value, element) => value + element) / _fps.length;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(

        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: OrientationBuilder(builder: (context, orientation) {
        return Center(

          child: Container(
            color: Colors.grey[850],
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      "Run!",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.blue[300],
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 20.0),
                    ),
                    Switch(
                        value: _isRunning,
                        onChanged: (bool val) => _toggleDynamic(val)
                        ),
                  ],
                ),
                Divider(),
                Container(
                  width: 400,
                  height: 400,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white, boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      blurRadius: 4.0,
                      spreadRadius: 2.0,
                    )
                  ]),
                  child: CustomPaint(
                    painter: MyPainter(_matrix, 400/_rowSize, _rowSize),//fill out the 400x400 container
                    isComplex: true,
                    willChange: true,
                  ),
                ),
                Divider(),
                Text(
                  "${_getAvgFps().toStringAsFixed(2)} FPS",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue[300]),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }),
    );
  }
}

class MyPainter extends CustomPainter {
  List _matrix;
  double _pixSize;
  int _rowSize;

  final redPaint = Paint()..color = Colors.red;
  final greenPaint = Paint()..color = Colors.green[900];
  final bluePaint = Paint()..color = Colors.blueGrey;
  final purplePaint = Paint()..color = Colors.purple;

  Paint getPaint(int code) {
    switch (code) {
      case 0:
        return bluePaint;
        break;
      case 1:
        return purplePaint;
        break;
      case 2:
        return greenPaint;
        break;
      case 3:
        return redPaint;
        break;
      default:
        return bluePaint;
    }
  }

  MyPainter(List matrix, double pixSize, int rowSize) {
    this._matrix = matrix;
    this._pixSize = pixSize;
    this._rowSize = rowSize;
  }

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    for (var i = 0; i < _matrix.length; i++) {
      var col = (i / _rowSize).floor();
      var row = i % _rowSize;
      canvas.drawRect(
          Rect.fromLTWH(col * _pixSize, row * _pixSize, _pixSize, _pixSize),
          getPaint(_matrix[i]));
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(MyPainter oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Maybe it would be faster to generate a bitmap as raw byte code and just display it on the canvas instead of drawing all those rectangles?

> P.S.[1]: I found `decodeImageFromPixels()` which looks promising, although quite a PITA at the same time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`decodeImageFromPixels()` and then drawing the Image from the callback onto a CustomPaint provided a satisfactory performance boost. Although still not at the level of Android+GLSurfaceView, it is still acceptable :)